# what is the best way to keep my gitlab server version updated

Tags: gitlab

I recently had to upgrade my Gitlab server. I found out that gitlab-7.8.1_omnibus is too old and there is no direct way to update the current version to the latest version gitlab-ee-12.7.6-ee. 
 
The best way I've found is to install a new server with the latest version of Gitlab and ask the users to transfer their data to the new server.

1. Is there a way I can transfer the data for the users?
2. I would like to prevent this from happening again. How do I make sure my Gitlab server is updated evey time a new version is available.
3. Do I must to run 'yum update' before I run the  Gitlab update?

Comment: I'm not sure whether your question fits this website or it could be on SuperUser. Because this is not a programming question. But after all, the simple answer to your question is to use one of the configuration management / IT Automation tools such as Puppet, Ansible, Chef, etc. to keep your gitlab machine updated. Read about them to find out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.**

GitLab 7.8.1 is indeed a very old version.
You can avoid upgrade path and just move Git repos, if your number of projects and their customisations and integrations is low.
Every clone of git repository is supposed to have all (or nearly all) history.

So you can just:

- create a matching project on the new GitLab server
- [add a new remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) to your git clones on your machine `git remote add origin ...`
- push to the new remote

**II.**

You can still try to upgrade your current server in several hops, see [upgrade recommendations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html#upgrade-recommendations):

> We recommend that you first upgrade to the latest available minor version within your major version

Old versions I could find are:

- 8.0.0 as the oldest [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/tags?page=30)
- 7.10.0 as the oldest [deb\rpm package](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce?page=194)
- 7.14.3 as the latest in 7.* release as [deb\rpm package](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce?page=187)

First make sure you minimize any customisations you have in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` as those parameters change a lot across versions, and require manual reconfiguration.

Then you can try:

1. upgrade to 7.14.3
2. then to 8.0.0
3. then to the last in 8.*
4. then to 9.0.0
   etc

**III.**

Once you have a stable recent version of GitLab server:

1. GitLab publishes new Major release yearly, and every Major.Minor release monthly (22nd day of the month), see [maintenance policy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/policy/maintenance.html), I really recommend upgrading **every month**
2. wait for a couple of weeks though, as they often release patches for bugs quickly found by other people
3. review release notes
4. read upgrade documentation
5. don't forget to backup
6. upgrade